# React Js not updating css files with build

Tags: reactjs

I have some problem with importing a css files inside a js ones :

js file (src/App.js):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MainApp from './MainApp.js';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props.className="App";
    };
    render() {
        return (
        <div class="App">
            <MainApp/>
        </div>
        )
    }
};
```

css file (src/App.css):

```css
:root {
    --primaryColor: #ffcf04;
    --secondaryColor: #ffed95;
    --colorAccent: #bb7c02;
}

.App {
    position : fixed;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    top : 0;
    left : 0;
    background: var(--secondaryColor);
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
```

My result on chromium:

```css
:root {
    --primaryColor: #ffcf04;
    --secondaryColor: #ffd881;
    --colorAccent: #bb7c02
}

.App {
    background: #ffcf04;
    background: var(--primaryColor);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed
}
```

while searching in the "Network" panel of the inspector, with a 200 return status.

It means that my nginx server provides the bad css file, so that react js is not using my actual css but an old version of it when I run "npm run build".

I am actually using nginx (with it working configuration) and react-js to build my project.

How do I disable the react-js cache? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jose Manuel de Frutos, the issue concerns React-JS ; I am not searching for a js issue but for a react-js issue, so for its configuration etc... this is the reasons of my reject. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need replace class="App" to className="App".

Comment: You can be right? because after modifying this it worked better... I give it an eye and I tell
For the moment I am actually taking some bad hours with vite

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup your build tools to give a unique `hash` string to the CSS file on every build. So the html file should have something like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-[hash].css">
```

Comment: After some instants it now seems to work, but the strange part was that this tool was already activated... (I have those lines after building : File sizes after gzip:

  55.29 kB (-4 B)  **build/static/js/main.c4d24bb3.js**
  1.79 kB          **build/static/js/787.59cbb831.chunk.js**
  632 B            **build/static/css/main.eddae2cf.css**
)